# Generate graph of include files in Visual Studio Community 2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I wanted to "Generate the graph of include files" in my C++ project, using Visual Studio 2019 Community, but that option doesn't appear when I right click, despite appearing (with the same project) in another PC, with Visual Studio 2017.
Did they remove it this year?

Comment: Maybe this is an addon. I don't remember seeing this functionality in Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: It may be that the community edition does not have that feature.

Comment: It worked with Enterprise edition

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Action `"Generate Graph Of Include Files"` is available only in **VS2019 Enterprise** edition, as part of the `Code Maps` module. It can be run i.e. via option in context menu within code file.