# Is there an option in Visual Studio that provides a simple view of how a file is included in my C++ code without building?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, include

So I have below code in my file mine.cpp,

```
#include <iostream>
#define max INT_MAX
```

The identifier "INT_MAX" will be undefined if I remove "#include <iostream>". So, I know it is defined somewhere in iostream.

When I go to the definition of INT_MAX it is in limits.h file. So, I guess limits.h is nested include in iostream.

Is there a way for me to view (like mine.cpp->iostream->...->limits.h) how limits.h is included in my mine.cpp **without building**.

I searched and found there are other similar questions but all answers related to them include "build with some option". I have to do this without building as my build takes quite some time to complete.

Comment: Well, you do have `/showIncludes`, but since you want it without building, that wouldn't be a proper answer. I don't think there is another way in VS to do so, so the only alternative would be to use some external tool. Doxygen is the first think i can think of, but TBH, while it definitely generates a classes tree, i don't recall if it's able to generate an includes tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a strange requirement:

> without building.

What exactly are you trying to avoid? Building the entire project/solution? To save time?

As noted by @dxiv and @Boris, you need to at least compile that file. More strictly - run a pre-processor on it to expand macros, conditional compilation, etc.

Compiling you file with `/showIncludes` and `/P` (preprocess to a file) technically doesn't "build", as the object file is not produced.

The generated output is hierarchical, so you get a complete path of inclusion.

You didn't mention the version and edition of your Studio; this post [Generate graph of include files in Visual Studio Community 2019](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55927503/generate-graph-of-include-files-in-visual-studio-community-2019) states that Enterprise edition of 2019 (and possible 2017) has `"Generate Graph Of Include Files"` feature. However, the process that it is using likely involves compiling or preprocessing :)

Comment: Thank you Vlad, "Generate Graph Of Include Files" is the best solution for me I guess, I have yet to try it (enterprise is only available at my workstation) but looking at the feature I think it'll help.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know that it is (reliably) possible to do it without at least compiling, since in the end it's the compiler that checks the include paths and dependencies.

However, compiling a single file with `#include <iostream>` should suffice, as opposed to building the entire project. For example, compiling the default "C++ console" `.cpp` generated by the wizard produces a `debug\sample.tlog\CL.read.1.tlog` file which contains the following towards the top.

```
<vs-path>\VC\TOOLS\MSVC\14.26.28801\INCLUDE\IOSTREAM      ***
<vs-path>\VC\TOOLS\MSVC\14.26.28801\INCLUDE\YVALS_CORE.H
<vs-path>\VC\TOOLS\MSVC\14.26.28801\INCLUDE\VCRUNTIME.H
<vs-path>\VC\TOOLS\MSVC\14.26.28801\INCLUDE\SAL.H
<vs-path>\VC\TOOLS\MSVC\14.26.28801\INCLUDE\CONCURRENCYSAL.H
<vs-path>\VC\TOOLS\MSVC\14.26.28801\INCLUDE\VADEFS.H
<vs-path>\VC\TOOLS\MSVC\14.26.28801\INCLUDE\XKEYCHECK.H
<vs-path>\VC\TOOLS\MSVC\14.26.28801\INCLUDE\ISTREAM        ***
<vs-path>\VC\TOOLS\MSVC\14.26.28801\INCLUDE\OSTREAM        ***
<vs-path>\VC\TOOLS\MSVC\14.26.28801\INCLUDE\IOS
<vs-path>\VC\TOOLS\MSVC\14.26.28801\INCLUDE\XLOCNUM        ***
<vs-path>\VC\TOOLS\MSVC\14.26.28801\INCLUDE\CLIMITS        ***
<vs-path>\VC\TOOLS\MSVC\14.26.28801\INCLUDE\LIMITS.H       <--
<vs-path>\VC\TOOLS\MSVC\14.26.28801\INCLUDE\CMATH
```

The above is a superset of the `#include` files that lead to `limits.h`. An inspection of the respective headers shows that the actual path is `iostream` `- istream` `- ostream` `- xlocnum` `- climits` `- limits.h`.

Comment: Thanks dxiv, but I wanted to avoid doing "inspectin of respective headers", whenever I click goto definition, I want to know if there is simple way to know how I got there.

Comment: Also thanks I'll try out compiling single file and see how it goes